# Laravel "Parse error" after clean Install

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-5.7

After installing `Laravel 5.7` on `Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit`

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in [CENSORED]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388
```

`php -v` outputs

```
PHP 7.2.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2018 11:40:04) ( NTS )
    Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
        with Zend OPcache v7.2.11-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999                                                                                                                                   -2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Already reinstalled / rebooted

Running VestaCP with Apache and Nginx

Comment: Probably malformed files. How did you transfer the files?

Comment: For reference, `[$value, $key] = static::explodePluckParameters($value, $key);` is *"Arr.php line 388"*. `["test", "value"] = "Testing";` definitely throws a syntax error for me, but that's in PHP 5.6.37

Comment: @emix via composer it was a clean install

Comment: Did you check the file ? This row is not accessible if you have PHP version problem.

Comment: is it the only error its giving?

Comment: @VincentDecaux I reinstalled it often times, what would I need to check tho?

Comment: @Kuldeep Yes also in the error log

Comment: Check the file itself. Do you have the same as https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php

Comment: have u tried any other laravel projects on the same system? just create a new empty project and check if that runs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code run only in php 7.1 and 7.2 and this syntax show you use php 7.0
change your php version to 7.1 or 7.2 and this solve your problem